ATT in longitudinal model using generalized estimating equation in the marginaleffects package
I fit a GEE in R. I have an observational study with a dichotomous grouping variable and I was wondering how to calculate the  ATT using the package Marginaleffects.
Lets say I have the model:
model <- y ~ time*group, clustered by ID.
avg_comparisons(model, variables = "group",
vcov = ~subclass,
newdata = subset(md, group == 1)
What makes me confused is the inclusion of the time interaction in my model. The examples that i have seen use a cross sectional calculations, so I am unsure if i need to explicitly include the time variable in the avg_comparisons()

ATT is applicable when your sample is a random sample from a population, which is very unusual in an intervention study.  Is your sample a random sample?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
